# Python PostgreSQL psycopg2 concatenate columns to new column

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I can concateante two columns using the following code:

```
engine = create_engine(f'postgresql+psycopg2://user:password@host/db')
result = engine.execute('SELECT concat(col_1, col_2) AS uid FROM db_table;')
```

and I can alter the table to create a new column:

```
engine.execute('ALTER TABLE db_table 
ADD COLUMN concat_1_2 VARCHAR NOT NULL;')
```

But how can I insert the result query into the table in an efficient way (very large number of rows)?

Comment: insert as new rows or updating existing rows ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you need  only an insert  you could use  an insert select

```
insert into db_table (concat_1_2 )
SELECT concat(col_1, col_2) 
FROM db_table
```

otherwise just use an update

```
UPDATE db_table
SET  concat_1_2 = concat(col_1, col_2)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace columns `col_1` and `col_2` with new one `col_1_2`, you can alter the table in this way:

```
alter table db_table alter col_1 type varchar using concat(col_1, col_2);
alter table db_table rename col_1 to col_1_2;
alter table db_table drop col_2;
```